# How to send current user from Angular app to Firebase realtime database rules through REST API

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've a small Angular application deployed to Firebase. There're only 2 users. The users are authenticated with their emails addresses. I'm able to get the user data in my Angular application.

In the development phase I've used the following Realtime Database rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Naturally, I'd like to make the full database only readable and writeable for that 2 users.

I've tried to set up the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "auth.uid !== null"
  }
}
```

As expected, I receive a 401 error.

My question would be, that how should I send the uid from within the Angular app endpoint requests?

I've tried sending it via path param, like:

```
this.http.get(`https://myappname.firebaseio.com/data.json?auth=${uid}`).toPromise();
```

But passing the logged in user's uid like this won't work. Should I send it with http headers? If yes, what should be the proper syntax?

Or do I need to send anything? Maybe I just need a better realtime database rule?

---

Edit:

I was able to retrieve the tokenId with the auth service's constructor.

```
this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe((user: any) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        user.getIdToken().then((idToken: any) => {
          this.idToken = idToken;
        });
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    });
```

Now when I call an API endpoint I just simply add the idToken as a path param, like this:

`` return this.http.get(`https://myapp.firebaseio.com/data.json?auth=${token}`).toPromise(); ``

And Realtime Database rule looks like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
}
```

Comment: One question: Why don't you use the JS SDK in your app? Any specific reason for using the RTDB REST API?

Comment: I've started building the Angular app based on an online course. Could elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Normally, when you have a web app interacting with the Firebase services, you use the JS SDK, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup. It is way easier than using the REST APIs (actually the JS SDK is a layer above the REST APIs).

Comment: I'm using the AngularFireAuth package imported from `@angular/fire/auth`.

In my service's constructor I'm getting the user data with the following [code](https://postimg.cc/SXbnbfBq).

Isn't this the "best practice"?

Comment: "Isn't this the "best practice"? This question is too broad to be answered here, unfortunately. It seems that you should get the token through your service. This is option 1 in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You interact between your Angular app and the Firebase Realtime Database with the [Realtime Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token), to send authenticated requests to the Realtime Database REST API through the `auth` query string parameter you need to generate and pass an **ID token**.

```
this.http.get(`https://myappname.firebaseio.com/data.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>`).toPromise();
```

To generate this ID token, you can

- Either retrieve it from the client (your Angular app) as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients);
- OR, use the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth), with the [`signInWithPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password) method (since your users are "authenticated with their emails addresses").

---

Note that an ID token is totally different from a user uid.

---

PS: Since you are setting your rules with `"auth.uid !== null"`, you may be interested by this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185640/3371862).