# Firebase email saying my Realtime Database Rules has insecure rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to piggy-back on a question asked years ago as I have the same rules [Firebase email saying my realtime database has insecure rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392059/firebase-email-saying-my-realtime-database-has-insecure-rules?rq=1)

Here is my Rules:[image: Security Rules]

1. All Sign-in Methods are disabled except for email/password.
2. I only have one account of email/password.
3. I don't allow anyone to log in - no GUI to log into.

So the question is: What else can I do to totally secure my Firebase Database? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to know that as soon as (1) someone has the Web API Key of your Firebase Project and (2) the email/password sign-in method is enabled, this person can use the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) and [sign-up to your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) (i.e. create a new account).

Getting the Web API Key is not very difficult if you deploy an app linked to your Firebase project (Android, iOS, Web...).

Consequently, rules only based on `"auth != null"` allow anyone that has signed-up through the REST API accessing your Realtime Database. **No need to use any GUI**: after having been identified through the Auth REST API, the user can use the [RTDB REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).

One classical approach to avoid "non-desired" users to access data, is to add one or more Custom Claims to the desired accounts and use these claims in the Security Rules: See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#working_with_authentication_custom_claims) for more details.