# Firestore: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

    match /documents/{any} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null
    }

    match /users/{any} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null
    }
}
```

So basically, I want users that are authenticated to be able to read/write to the `users` and `documents` collections. But I try to write when I create a user and signin:

```
                const registerRes = await firebase
                    .auth()
                    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                await registerRes.user.updateProfile({
                    displayName: fullName
                });
                registerRes.user.sendEmailVerification();
                await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(registerRes?.user?.uid).set({...someStuff});
```

But I get an error:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#writing_rules), you need to include your path specific rules in a `match /databases/{database}/documents` block like:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /documents/{any} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null
    }

    match /users/{any} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null
    }


  }
}
```

---

Side note: Be aware that rules that are **only** based on `request.auth.uid != null` are not really securing your DB, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185274/firebase-email-saying-my-realtime-database-rules-has-insecure-rules/66185640?stw=2#66185640).