# How to secure Firebase by checking for correct userID in the "official" Authentication database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have users, registered with the EMail function of Firebase Authentication.
Only authenticated users should write to my Firestore database.

**My rule** (from the documentation):

```
allow write: if request.auth != null;
```

allows access to every request where there is an non-null auth-object. This doesn't seem to be very secure. As you could just make a request with any `auth = {something: "hacker"}` object.

So, to avoid this problem. How do I check if the given `request.auth.uid` is actually the one from the Firebase Authentication service?

Comment: You may be interested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185274/firebase-email-saying-my-realtime-database-rules-has-insecure-rules/66185640?stw=2#66185640.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request.auth` variable is populated by Firebase automatically on the server, based on the ID token that is sent along from the client with each request. Minting an ID token for a given Firebase project, requires that you have access to the administrative credentials for that project.

This means that, as long as you ensure that you don't share the administrative credentials for your project publicly, nobody can inject their own information into the ID token, and this the `request.auth` object in your database is actually secure from tampering.

---

The rule in your question limits **who** can write data, as the user will need to be signed in to Firebase Authentication to be able to write. You'll typically also want to limit **what** the user can do, both by controlling the access (for example, only letting them [access their own data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access)), and by [validating the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/data-validation) that they write.

Comment: Makes sense to me. I got a little bit worried, because in the Firebase rules playground you can edit your custom request. Everytime i gave an empty auth-object, Firebase still  granted access.

Comment: The rules playground runs in the Firebase console and can only be accessed by collaborators on the project. As such it is an example of an environment that has access to the administrative credentials of the project.

Answer (score 1):

These set of rules worked for me.

```js
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```