# How can I ban a User in Firebase realtime Database using the rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've created a list of banned users in my realtime Database and I want to make them impossible to log-in, I know I can use the database rules, but I don't know how, can someone help me?

This is my database structure:

```
/banned-users:
    /UserId1:True
    /UserId2:True
```

Those are my database rules:

```js
{
    "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [reference data in other paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#referencing_data_in_other_paths) as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "thepath": {
          ".read": "root.child('banned-users').child(auth.uid).val() !== true"
          ".write": "root.child('banned-users').child(auth.uid).val() !== true"
      }
    }
}
```

---

Note that actually you don't "make them impossible to log-in", because [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185640/3371862), but you prevent them writing to/reading from your database.

Comment: i' know but it makes impossible for them to use the app

Comment: Perfect! I just wanted to be complete and emphasize this important aspect, as explained in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185640/3371862).